# Can't check Meteor Version in Terminal

Tags: meteor, version, throw

`[react-pocketscholar (master)]$ meteor --version`

`/Users/ftrflyr/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.4_3.1v4v008++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
            ^`

`Error: EEXIST, symlink '/Users/ftrflyr/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.4_3.1v4v008++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle'`
[react-pocketscholar (master)]$ meteor -v

`/Users/ftrflyr/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.4_3.1v4v008++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/meteor-promise/promise_server.js:165
      throw error;
            ^`

`Error: EEXIST, symlink '/Users/ftrflyr/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.4_3.1v4v008++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle'`

Answer (score 2):

**1. Global tool version of meteor command**

Find version by:

```
meteor --version
```

**2. Project version of meteor**

A project stays at the meteor version which it was created with unless manually upgraded. Find this by running:

```
cat .meteor/release
```

Another way to do this is to open up your Javascript console in the browser and type:

```
console.log(Meteor);
```

This is very useful for me as I'm running Ubuntu on a Chromebook so I don't need to stop my local server to check which version I'm currently running.

Please note the server does need to be running (localhost:3000) for this command to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in a meteor project repository and type meteor --version